# Clear data after submit button from text box and labels

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have a web form that asks for the mobile number and id, if the id or mobile are incorrect. the web page will display an error label, after this error label if i entered a correct information this form will be not visible anymore and a new div will be visible with another display. so here the problem is when the customer enters the new info after a wrong info, if he clicks back the label is still appearing and text box 2, i have set these elements to:

```
lblfailedresponce.Text = ""  // 1rsst text box 
txtMobilePhone.Text = ""     //2nd text box
TransactionID.Text = ""      // label
```

but it didn't work and they still appear. so what is the code in the submit button that i have to do to clear the cache or the fields from the invisible form?

Comment: please elaborate "  if he clicks back the label is still appearing ..." clicking browser back button?

Comment: yes label still appearing on the old error performed and yes browser back button . 
txtMobilePhone.Text = String.Empty;
lblfailedresponce.Text = String.Empty; not working too

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
txtMobilePhone.Text = String.Empty;
lblfailedresponce.Text = String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // clear error label if the user clicks on the text box.
        $('#txtMobilePhone').click(function(){
            if('#lblfailedresponce').val()!=null)
            {
                 $('#lblfailedresponce').val()='';
            }
            $('#txtMobilePhone').val()='';
            $('#TransactionID').val()='';
        });

        $('#TransactionID').click(function(){
            if('#lblfailedresponce').val()!=null)
            {
                 $('#lblfailedresponce').val()='';
            }
            $('#txtMobilePhone').val()='';
            $('#TransactionID').val()='';
        });
    });

</script>
```

This is a script that will serve the purpose. Kindly use this at the page bottom and see how it works.Hope this will help you.

I assume the element Id of the text boxes and its name are same. Kindly change it if its otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a caching issue then you could add `Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)` to your page load.  That will make it so the browser will not cache the page.

Another option is that you could set your error label to `visible=false` and then make it visible in the code that checks your error.  But then the next load after that the error label will not show as visible.